# Struggling to understand the copy past code. -Openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to understand the code to implement in my project. Below code using openpyxl.

```
def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []
    #Loops through selected Rows
    for i in range(startRow,endRow + 1,1):
        #Appends the row to a RowSelected list
        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)
            #Adds the RowSelected List and nests inside the rangeSelected
            rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

     return rangeSelected
```

In line 5 where the for loop starts (startRow,endRow + 1,1) what is the purpose of "1"? i get "startRow, endRow+1" but I am struggling to get my head around "1".

Comment: Have you read the docs on [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)?

Comment: The third argument to `range` defines the step size, if you had `range(0, 10, 2)`, it would give you `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`. `1` is the default value for that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range

Answer (score -1):

You should read the documentation. It's the range() function step input. check this :

> range(start, stop, step)

You can read it here too :

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp

Comment: It was not me, but some people will downvote an answer if the question itself is not a "good" one. I think to discourage people from answering "bad" questions. Alternatively, if you look at your answer compared to the comment in the question from @Talon, their comment might actually provide more of an answer than your actual answer. I recommend that you flush out your answer perhaps with an example. I cannot speak for the actual downvoter though. It is just one of the things you need to accept if you post answers.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will keep this in mind next time. I worked it out when I started using the range function. I should have dig a bit deeper before asking the question.

Comment: I don't think that your action was a bad thing to ask what you don't know. But not here. Stackoverflow has strict rules. I don't agree with all of their rules. I contact them sometimes about it. but till the moment these rules are in place, we should consider following them. So, yes... Search and read the docs and other questions before asking questions, And If you are going to ask a question, keep it straight, clear, and general. Wish you the best.